# Integrate the drupal distribution with already existing site

Tags: 7

I have already existing Drupal 7 site, now I got a requirement for the jobs portal for the same site, I found there is a nice drupal distribution [Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) which exactly satisfies my requirements.

I want to know is there any way that I can integrate this distribution with my existing site, so that i can access the functionality of this distribution from my existing site drupal dashboard, please let me know, I searched a lot on this but did not got any relevant info.

I am thinking of one more option if I will create a multisite on my existing drupal site then can I install this distribution on my multisite.

If any option among these two is possible then please let me know, otherwise I have to create a new installation of Drupal and I do not want two dashboards one of my existing site and other of this distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Recruiter Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter_features) module?

You can simply download and enable this feature instead of the install profile and see if it does what you need.